# struct bitfield conversion from uint

Tags: c++, struct, unions

I am struggling writing a c class containing several union struct bitfields which should convert to uint8_t.
yes, I am aware this is a dangerous design as it relies on the architecture... but please help me to fix it that way.

my full code can be found here: https://gist.github.com/nerdyscout/cd6a2e257053a87f994f9a51a0b1c9be
the (most likely) critical parts are

```
template <uint16_t MCP3x6x_DEVICE_TYPE>
class MCP3x6x {
  typedef union {
    struct {
      enum adc_mode        : 2;
      enum cs_sel cs_sel   : 2;
      enum clk_sel clk_sel : 2;
      uint8_t config0      : 2;
    } config0 = MCP3x6x_DEFAULT_CONFIG0;

    inline status_t write() { return _write(_data, MCP3x6x_CMD_IWRITE | MCP3x6x_ADR_CONFIG0); };
    inline status_t read() { return _read(_data, MCP3x6x_CMD_IREAD | MCP3x6x_ADR_CONFIG0); };

   private:
    uint8_t _data;
  } config0_t;


  union {
    struct registers{
      config0_t config0;
// ...other members...
    } settings_default = {MCP3x6x_DEFAULT_CONFIG0, MCP3x6x_DEFAULT_CONFIG1,   MCP3x6x_DEFAULT_CONFIG2,
                  MCP3x6x_DEFAULT_CONFIG3, MCP3x6x_DEFAULT_IRQ,       MCP3x6x_DEFAULT_MUX,
                  MCP3x6x_DEFAULT_SCAN,    MCP3x6x_DEFAULT_TIMER,     MCP3x6x_DEFAULT_OFFSETCAL,
                  MCP3x6x_DEFAULT_GAINCAL, MCP3x6x_DEFAULT_RESERVED1, MCP3x6x_DEFAULT_RESERVED2,
                  MCP3x6x_DEFAULT_LOCK,    MCP3x6x_DEVICE_TYPE, 0x0000};

    inline status_t write() {
      return _write(settings, MCP3x6x_CMD_IWRITE | MCP3x6x_ADR_CONFIG0, 28);
    };
    inline status_t read() {
      return _read(this->_data, MCP3x6x_CMD_IREAD | MCP3x6x_ADR_CONFIG0, 28);
    };

   private:
    uint8_t _data[28];
  } settings;
}
```

error log

```
In file included from /home/user/Projects/lib_MCP3x6x/examples/analogRead/analogRead.ino:11:
src/MCP3x6x.h: In instantiation of 'constexpr MCP3x6x<15>::<unnamed union>::<constructor>()':
src/MCP3x6x.h:381:62:   required from 'MCP3x6x<MCP3x6x_DEVICE_TYPE>::MCP3x6x(uint8_t, SPIClass*) [with short unsigned int MCP3x6x_DEVICE_TYPE = 15; uint8_t = unsigned char]'
/home/user/Projects/lib_MCP3x6x/examples/analogRead/analogRead.ino:13:9:   required from here
src/MCP3x6x.h:364:27: error: could not convert 'MCP3x6x_DEFAULT_CONFIG0' from 'const uint8_t' {aka 'const unsigned char'} to 'MCP3x6x<15>::config0_t'
  364 |     } settings_default = {MCP3x6x_DEFAULT_CONFIG0, MCP3x6x_DEFAULT_CONFIG1,   MCP3x6x_DEFAULT_CONFIG2,
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                           |
      |                           const uint8_t {aka const unsigned char}
```

full error log:https://gist.github.com/nerdyscout/ef7e8a89ba6a99e3e1f78d2d02f3ab87

According to the error `src/MCP3x6x.h:369:19: error: could not convert 'MCP3x6x_DEFAULT_CONFIG0' from 'const uint8_t' {aka 'const unsigned char'} to 'MCP3x6x<15>::config0_t'` the value of default_config0 (=uint_8t) can not be converted to config0_t which I do not know how to resolve, I would have suspected this should happen with _data in the same union.
oh and using those enums seems to break something as well, havn't figured out what that is.

Comment: Please try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Besides the [mre] (where you also add comments on the lines where you get errors) also please copy-paste (as text) the full and complete  error into the question.

Comment: initial post is updated, I hope this helps.

Comment: In C++ you cannot use a `union` for this.  But you can use `memcpy`.

Comment: Hi Ben, I assume you missunderstood my intention. 
https://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dab/cs1410/textbook/5.Structures/unions.html
the union should allow access to the whole byte or single enums.